# How setting session expired time use code on ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm **not use FormsAuthenticatio**.

When the user Login, I will save the user info to on session like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = model.Id;
HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] = model.Name
```

But How I set the session expired time **use code**?

Maybe only for 30 minute, Maybe User select **"Remember Me"** then save it 24 hour.

Second question is : If I'm already set it expired time on web.config like:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
```

Then How about the **priority** ? config first or code first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set session in code, `global.asax` on `session_start` event using this.

`Session.Timeout = 24*60 ;`

I have checked in code that, setting session in `code` like above override that in `web.config`. So the above has more priority and this will be used and `web.config`'s value will be discarded.

Comment: must in ``global.aspx`` on ``session_start`` ?? can't I just execute ``HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout == 24*60 `` on any where? like controller?

Comment: No, it has to be `global.asax`, Use this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx. It says `The Timeout property can be set in the Web.config file for an application using the timeout attribute of the sessionState configuration element, or you can set the Timeout property value directly using application code.`

Comment: I don' understand ``set the Timeout property value directly using application code.`` that not mean I can directly use code on controller?

Comment: If I need add it to ``global.aspx`` on ``session_start``. did you mean I need access the method from controller? else I think it will be execute on every request. but I need set it only when user Login

Comment: I have tried with putting in `controller` and that works too!

Comment: @qakmak , is this helpful, or let me know, you need further help!

Comment: I'll try more and will give you answer, please give me more time.

Comment: @qakmak , yes, definitely , take your time and try, if you discover something new, post that too!

Comment: When using session storage `InProc`, changing the session timeout to 24 hours is unwise. Your session will be lost when IIS recycles the app pool. IIS recycles by default after 20 minutes of inactivity, or every 29 hours. If someone logs in during hour 18 of the app pool lifetime, they'll be logged out after 11 hours, not 24.

Comment: @StevenV, yes you are right, but when someone intended to set any value to `sessio-timeout` , app pool setting has to be taken care of. I mean you can override the `29` hours setting!

Comment: @ArindamNayak, I'm not test on IIS, but I test it use visual studio debug. the web.config is :  ``<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />``  and I'm create a class and access it from ``Action``. ``HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = TimeOut;`` it works fine.

Comment: @StevenV, Also thanks, My IIS setting the recycles time every day morning 5 AM. so it's fine let the session lose on that time. If I want keep session for long time, I will save it to database or Memcache something.

Comment: @qakmak , good to know that, it works! , When you deploy this to `IIS`, you need to set  `App poll lifetime` as it defaults to 29 hours, if you are intended to make session timeout more than that.

Comment: @ArindamNayak, I'm not find it on IIS7. I only set the Recycling:``Regular Time Interval(minute) : 0``.  ``Spefic Times : 06:00:00`` and set  Process Model:``Idle Time-out(minute): 0 ``

Comment: @qakmak , if this setting is fine with you, then it is good enough,  but this link has explanation - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733120(v=ws.10).aspx. `EDIT` - Got it, i was referring to `Regular Time Interval(minute)` , default value for this is 29 hours , and this is checked by default, if you had overridden this, then your are good enough to start.

Answer (score 0):

if the user ticks "Remember Me", just add a random guid to a database of active users and give them a cookie with the same guid. when the user comes back without a valid session, check for the cookie and search the database for the guid. if valid, the user is signed in

Comment: if you change the web.config for one request it will change for all requests even if they don't tick the checkbox