# Is it possible to increase special session timeout in mvc?

Tags: session, timeout, asp-net-mvc-1

Is it possible to increase special session timeout in mvc?

something like :

```
Session.Timeout = 30;
Session["example"] = obj;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How setting session expired time use code on ASP.NET MVC5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327679/how-setting-session-expired-time-use-code-on-asp-net-mvc5)

Comment: Then see [How set a Session variable expired time on MVC 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26333375/7914637) topic.